# Pulling in content from another page

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm using advanced custom fields and Im trying to pull content from sub pages onto the homepage

The below works but I was wondering whether it was possible to do this automatically and not write static ids on the fields?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <?php the_field('content', 5); ?>
    </li>

    <li>
        <?php the_field('content', 6); ?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The page setup is like:

home

-parent page

--sub page

--sub page

Any ideas would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [`get_children()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children)

```
<?php
$children = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => get_the_ID() ) );
if ( $children ) {
    foreach( $children as $child ) { ?>
        <li>
            <?php the_field( 'content', $child->ID ); ?>
        </li>
    <?php }
```